# Laptop display malfunction?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, battery

I just came home from school and turned on my computer from sleep mode, and this showed up

[image]

Yesterday I had to put my laptop on sleep mode on battery for the night, because I had to charge my phone, if that matters. I plugged it back in as I woke up. What's the problem?

Comment: Where do you leave your laptop? Trying to rule out someone stepping on it. Because ive seen quite a few that are not cracked but have been stepped on and are like above. Could you also put the laptop specs and brand?

Comment: Acer Aspire E 15, you can see all of the specs in google. Also, my resolution goes off and on now, it usually doesn't. There's like a small distortion, as if Its the plastic is not connected, but just a BIT, at the right edge of my laptop's monitor, I've been always worried that, that might cause problems, do you think it might be that? I keep it on my desk all the time no one could have stepped on it.

Comment: Did you try reverting your graphics drivers or rolling them back to see if it goes away? .

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary, It's only the second time that happened and last time was like two months ago. It's not like I get it often.

Comment: Okay so its happened before. Stress test it with [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) and enable the logs so if it messes up you can see what caused the issues.

Comment: How do I enable the logs?

Comment: Did you restart your computer (should always be the 1st troubleshooting step)?

Comment: I did the test but I can't find the logs, although I enabled them. The problem didnt happen while testing. Through the whole time I had 51~ degrees. Well, when it happened I just put it to sleep again and woke it up, and then it fixed itself.

Comment: And I meant that might brightness goes a bit dim, not my resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here:

- Display is physically damaged
- Video memory is dying
- Video connector is damaged
- Memory faulted in sleep mode

The first option can be verified by turning your laptop off and look for cracks. Another option is to carefully tap/push on a side of the display (also the display itself) and look if it starts acting weird, you should not push too hard for obvious reasons (clean fingers may help too :)).

The second option can be verified by a memory check and a video memory check. There are lots of programs for that on the internet. If your OS comes with a memory tool, use that.

The third option can be checked by slowly turning your screen fully open and look for when it starts to flicker or crack.

The last option is the easiest one to solve. Just execute a clean reboot and all should be fine again.

If there is any physical damage you can take it back to the store if you like.